# Need to move row from one google spreadsheet to a completely different google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to move a row from one spreadsheet to a completely different spreadsheet based on a cell.  I have a script that I can make work if the sheets are in the same file but not two different files.  The first file was created by a form responses and the other file is a spreadsheet I manually created.  Here is my script:

```
function onEdit() {
 var sheetNameToWatch = "Form Responses 1";
 var columnNumberToWatch = 11;
 var valueToWatch = "Y";
 var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Completed Repairs";
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1VpSqsR_zBU6FhEfVW5QJi2-oAvVhxnxSQmoINz_J5-Y");
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

 if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
   var targetSheet = ts.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
   var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
   sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1,sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
   sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
 }
}
```

Comment: Use the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) and step through your code line by line, until you see where the error is.  Have you viewed the Execution Transcript under the VIEW menu?  Does it state that the code completed?

Comment: Are you sure the active sheet is the sheet you want? Since you opened a new sheet, is it assured whether the active sheet will be one or another?

Comment: Here is the transcript. [15-07-07 07:58:33:304 CDT] Starting execution
[15-07-07 07:58:33:310 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[15-07-07 07:58:33:326 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.openById([1VpSqsR_zBU6FhEfVW5QJi2-oAvVhxnxSQmoINz_J5-Y]) [0.015 seconds]
[15-07-07 07:58:33:326 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[15-07-07 07:58:33:327 CDT] Sheet.getActiveCell() [0 seconds]
[15-07-07 07:58:33:340 CDT] Sheet.getName() [0.013 seconds]
[15-07-07 07:58:33:340 CDT] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[15-07-07 07:58:33:341 CDT] Execution succeeded [0.031 seconds total runtime]

Comment: If I edit the spreadsheet, then I get this under transcript:
[15-07-07 08:40:06:920 CDT] Starting execution
[15-07-07 08:40:06:925 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl([https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VpSqsR_zBU6FhEfVW5QJi2-oAvVhxnxSQmoINz_J5-Y]) [0 seconds]
[15-07-07 08:40:06:928 CDT] Execution failed: You do not have permission to perform that action. (line 6, file "Code") [0.002 seconds total runtime]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing this error `Execution failed: You do not have permission to perform that action.`, because you cannot call Built-in Google Services(openById) from onEdit() function.

Simple triggers run in a limited auth mode that doesn't allow opening other spreadsheets. You can create an installable trigger ([details in that help page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)) to run your onEdit script with full auth.

Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) for more details on simple triggers and the restrictions for the triggers.

Hope that helps!