# SpreadsheetApp.getActive() returns null for form

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Form which contains the following script. Each time it fails because `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` returns null. Any ideas as to why?

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var courseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Courses");
}
```

The error I get is `TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null. (line 6, file "")`

I have found lots of examples online which shows usage in this way so I'm sure it's possible. Could it be a permissions issue with the spreadsheet that my form is linked to?

Comment: there isnt much to do from onOpen in a form. move the code to the spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm trying to get to a point where I can use a column in a spreadsheet to fill a list in a form. From the spreadsheet can I push values into the form?

Comment: yes. official docs have samples that modify a form.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be the use of

```
.getActive()
```

from a form. There is no active spreadsheet in use when the form is opened. Try instead:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById('id')
```

You can get the id out of the url. looks something like this:

> d/10r8Pv03S8qfMiA7dET2KNRmy0DEEExxPld42HjW-aX2c/

The numbers and letters between the slashes "/" are the id.

Comment: Using `openById` results in a permissions error. `You do not have permission to call openById`

Comment: Can't reproduce that error. Could be a problem with the limited auth mode of the trigger (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122893/google-apps-script-error-you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-openbyid?lq=1), can you try to set a trigger for the form (onopen) to force reauthorization?

Answer (score 0):

Developing on @Albrecht's diagnosis and solution, I made the lookup of the spreadsheet dynamic with:

```js
let form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId());
```

If you are attaching a script to the spreadsheet and want to get the form, you can use:

```js
let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let form = FormApp.openByUrl(spreadsheet.getFormUrl());
```